# When installing engineered wood on stairs does the nosing have to be one piece?

Tags: flooring

I am considerin installing engineered wood on stairs -does the nosing have to be one piece or it can be built from two segments like some of the below ?

I am considering installing engineered wood on stairs

I am looking at this example and it seems that it is acceptable.

Are there any code restrictions that would not allow this ?
If you know of other examples like this please share[image]

Ps this will cover existing steps

Answer (score 1):

That should work ok as long as the tread material is glued down well and it is a wood product, not MDF or even LVP, the latter needs to run full length, IMO. I prefer all nosings to run full length, again my preference. Clean the original treads of old finish and hopefully they are reasonably flat. You will need to cut the original extension of the nosing so the new riser material covers it properly.

Comment: And, OP, note that joints are staggered.

Comment: Yes staggering is a must.